# Installing Recent Release of JDK Using Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, installation, java

Can somebody tell me how to do this? Or, point me to a good link? 
I want to install Jmeter but "./jmeter" tells me that:

> Error: no `server' JVM at`C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.6.0\bin\server\jvm.dll'.

So, I need to get the server JVM up and running. 
I have been attempting to download and install the JDK from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html

And got a corrupted file error when I tried to install:

jdk-6u25-linux-ia64-rpm.bin

Should I be doing this via wget or apt-cyg? Or, how do i determine which installation
package I should be downloading from the oracle/sun downloads page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are on Windows so you should try the Windows x86 version unless there is a particular reason why you want to do that with Cygwin. Or try this:

- Copy 'server' folder from the JDK's JRE's bin folder (example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\bin\server)
- Paste the 'server' folder to JRE's bin folder (example: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0\bin)

Answer (score 3):

Cygwin aims for Linux source compatibility, but it does not provide Linux binary compatibility. This means that programs have to be built specifically for Cygwin and that Linux binaries such as the linux-ia64 JVM mentioned here will not run on Cygwin.

Perhaps it is possible to build the OpenJDK JVM for Cygwin, but it doesn't ship with Cygwin. The [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports) repository contains a package for the lightweight [JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net).

But in any case, JMeter was looking for the native Windows version of the JVM, so you probably just want to install that, as Jano already suggested.